# Spring-session with hazelcast, failed to autowire HazelcastInstance

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, spring-session

Failed to run spring-session with hazelcast with exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.web.http.HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration.setHazelcastInstance(org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider,org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider);
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.session.hazelcast.config.annotation.SpringSessionHazelcastInstance()}
```

I worked from the same sample in spring-session [reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html#security-spring-configuration)  but using XML confuration, and already have 
`<context:annotation-config />` in the appContext.xml

```
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession 
@Configuration
public class SessionConfig {
    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
                .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

        Config config = new Config();
        config.getMapConfig(HazelcastSessionRepository.DEFAULT_SESSION_MAP_NAME) 
                .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(
                        HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));
        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config); 
    }
}
```

Versions:
Java 1.8 - spring 4.3.3 - spring-session 2.0.2 - Hazelcast 3.9

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you create a @Bean in your config which returns an ObjectProvider?

Comment: ClassCastException, cannot cast HazelcastInstance to ObjectProvider.  
The point is, HazelcastHttpSessionConfiguration use ObjectProvider<HazelcastInstance> to autowire hazelcastInstance

Comment: Could you please try to just set up the hazelcast config as a Bean instead of creating the instance yourself?

Comment: @Bean
    public Config hazelCastConfig(){
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("hazelcast-instance")
                .addMapConfig(
                        new MapConfig()
                                .setName("configuration")
                                .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(-1));
        return config;
    }

Comment: Same exception, also tried setting Hazelcast through xml config <hz:hazelcast id="hazelcastInstance"> ... still giving the same exception.
Thank you for following up with me.

Comment: Now I would start debugging the springframework and see what happens.